# Entity framework 6 add-migration adding all tables/entities in Migration Script

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to run the code first migration in entity framework 6.0. I have added 4 new entities in my entities modal. However when i run the "add-migration" command in VS 2013, the generated migration file contains the script of all entitles (just like the initial migration) in my modal, though they are already in linked database. Obviously when I rum "Update-Database" commends, it generates entity already exists error. My DBContext  class looks like following:

```
public class BidstructDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BidstructDbContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Bidstruct") 
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }

    // New Added Table
    public DbSet<Gadgets> Gadgets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Language { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LanguageKeys> TranslationKeys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Translations> Translations { get; set; }


    static BidstructDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }      

}
```

and DatabaseInitializer class looks like as following:

```
public class DatabaseInitializer :
// CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BidstructDbContext>      // when model is stable
DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BidstructDbContext> // when iterating
{
    private const int AttendeeCount = 1000;

    // EF is NOT a good way to add a lot of new records.
    // Never has been really. Not built for that.
    // People should (and do) switch to ADO and bulk insert for that kind of thing
    // It's really for interactive apps with humans driving data creation, not machines
    private const int AttendeesWithFavoritesCount = 4;

    protected override void Seed(BidstructDbContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Any idea, how to resolve this problem. Its was working fine for me few days back but now I am facing this problem :(

Comment: Have you tried `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` instead of `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`? As the name suggests this will re-create the database if you've added models.

Comment: Tried after using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion and result is same

Comment: Do you have the initial migration files in your migration folder which has the existing tables.

Comment: What is the error? Can you post the generated code from firing up Add-Migration

Comment: @J.W, Yes I have initial migration file in migration folder.

Comment: @ Louis Michael, there is no error, generated migration file contains script to create all tables  instead of new added entities tables as show in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your context keys have changed, in your migration history.

I'm working on a project that has been using automatic migrations, but the automatic migration was not occurring due to a lot of class changes. In trying to switch to non-automatic migration, Add-Migration was regenerating the entire schema. 
So I tried putting the manual table changes into the Up() of the DbMigration, and this applied a migration and an entry into the __MigrationHistory table, but with a different context key (the namespace and class name of my configuration file.)

A quick test of renaming the previous (older) migration record's context key to be the same as the current one caused the migration up/down to generate correctly.

Even then...it may not be 100%. Most of my changes were correct, but it started out adding a table which already existed, then turned around and removed it.